# Is there a way to force an attachment to be either viewed in the browser, or downloaded?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, download, attachment

Within our cross browser web app, the client can upload different file types (.pdf, .eml, .jpg, etc.).

The client has requested a standardized way of viewing these attachments, either by opening it in the browser, or downloading the attachment.

I have looked at the `content-disposition` header to force the download of the document, but will this work across all browsers? What about default browser applications, won't they try and open the file directly in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#Browser_compatibility content-disposition response header is compatible with all browsers. So, if you need to force a download use Content-Disposition: attachment (and the file will always be downloaded). It is recommended to specify a filename also, and probably a content type:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg
```

If you skip the header, or just use content-disposition:inline then the browser will try to open the file inline.

Comment: I'm glad to see the documentation indicates that a standard cross-browser behavior is expected. If the client however decides to go with the inline option, but there is no default application to view the attachment, eg. a .eml file, how would the browser react?

Comment: As far as I know, if the browser can not open the file, it will prompt the user for download. You can test it with your browsers: open a file inline (from your server) with a non-standard extension and with a content-type application/octet-stream

Answer (score 1):

For these cases, I use the download attribute on the  tag.

```
<a href='./download-file.pdf' download='Name of File for user'>Click me to download</a>
```